# How can I back up data from MSN 6?

Tags: windows-xp, email, backup, windows-live-messenger

I am reinstalling windows for a friend. He has a large number of emails saved on his computer downloaded through MSN6. These emails are not reachable through webmail and he wants to keep them. I assume they're in some kind of database file. Where is this file located, and how can I back it up in a way that it will be accessible by the new version of MSN that I download.

Sorry for the basic questions but I learned how to use computers on Mac OS and linux so I'm not much of a Windows power user.

Comment: I have no reference point with MSN 6, but I *guess* it is similar to Outlook Express. If that is the case, then Windows Live Mail can import the files. The easiest way to check is to find out whether the database files end in `.dbx`.

Comment: Apparently there was something buried in settings that could do it.